# By setting x equal to the appropriate values in the binomial expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have this equation,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} $$

the answer is 0 derived by,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} = (1-1)^n = 0$$

How come   $$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} $$
is same as $$ (1-1)^n $$ ??

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "*how come it ends up with zero?*"  Which step specifically do you not understand?  Going from $(1-1)^n$ to $0$?  You should know that $(1-1)=0$ and $0^n = 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Are you not sure why $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} = (1-1)^n$?  This is a *direct* application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: It is **not actually $0$** : it is $1$ for $n=0$ and $0$ for $0<n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial theorem states that $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}$$.

Now substitute $x=1$ and $y=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ odd, it should be obvious: you are adding and subtracting successive binomial coefficients in Pascal's triangle.  If $n=3$ your sum is $1-3+3-1$, where each binomial coefficient occurs twice, once with a $+$ sign and once with a $-$ sign.

For even $n$, consider that each entry in row 4 (say) is the sum of two entries in row 3, by the well known recursion.  Your sum for $n=4$ is $1-4+6-4+1$ which we should
think of as $(0+1) - (1+3) + (3+3) - (3+1) - (1+0)$ which shows the binomial coefficients from the $n=3$ row canceling.